# Issue with Keras when calling Dense

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Ive been trying to run this code below and it keeps throwing out an error.

This is the code im trying to run on ipython. Can someone tell me what the issue is?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from util import getKaggleMNIST
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Input

xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest = getKaggleMNIST()

N, D = xtrain.shape
k = len(set(ytrain))

i = Input(shape=(D,))
x = Dense(500, activation='relu')(i)
x = Dense(300, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(k, activation='softmax')(k)

model = Model(inputs=i, outputs=x)

model.compile( loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'] )

r = model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, validation_data=(Xtest, Ytest), epochs=15, batch_size=32)

print("Returned:", r)

plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='loss') 
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss') 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError: Layer dense_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <type 'int'>. Full input: [10]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: shouldn't it b 
x = Dense(k, activation='softmax')(x) instand of 
x = Dense(k, activation='softmax')(k) ?

Comment: Thank you very much @JérémyBlain :)

Answer (score 0):

replace `x = Dense(k, activation='softmax')(k)` with `x = Dense(k, activation='softmax')(x)`